# How to copy individual non adjacent cells and disable copy (in between cells) to windows clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I have a range of cells e.g `(“A1:A6”)` , then I have used CTRL to copy only cells `“A1”` and `“A6”` .
If I opened another file e.g (notepad) ,then paste , I found out that all the values of range `(“A1:A6”)` are pasted and not just “A1” and “A6”. 
Is MS has been designed excel like that or I do copy individual cells wrongly.